# Stackbar chart in dcjs split by dimension

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am trying to create a stack bar chart in dcjs. The dcjs stack bar examples are quite clear the huge difference from the barchart with that of stack is that the stack function. The stack function takes the same group as input and it can take third parameter as function which decides by which value it has to split. I rather want a dimension to be split the entire bar chart.

Lets say the following data point is something like this

```
data = [
  {activity:"A1",time_taken:10,activity_group:"Master A"},
  {activity:"A2",time_taken:20,activity_group:"Master B"},
  {activity:"A1",time_taken:30,activity_group:"Master C"},
  {activity:"A2",time_taken:15,activity_group:"Master D"}
]
```

I want to have activity group in x-axis split by its activity representing time taken on y-axis, like this:

[image: goal]

How do I achieve this ?

Comment: By "split the entire bar chart", do you mean that you want each of the stacked bars to add up to 100% of the Y axis?

Comment: Yes and I want to add them by their own unit rather than making it to 100%. If you can see this link https://pasteboard.co/IEstrBP.png this shows what I want.

Comment: Do you want them individually colored like that? dc.js usually colors each "stack" one color, so Master A and Master B would be say blue and Master C and Master D orange. In dc.js have to be the same number of stacks for each X value, but you can work around that by zeroing out any extras. If you wanted individual coloring you could make every value into its own stack, as long as you zero out the rest of the domain. There's lots of ways to do it, not sure what you're trying to do yet.

Comment: I am really not concerned about the color of the chart, I am happy with what dc.js creates. I am wondering how to bisect a dimension something like activity group to split the data. I am not sure about the approach for this. I can imagine having a dimension activity and using that create group which gives sum of time_taken now how do i split that across activity_group ?

Comment: Please refer my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/goxrt27q/ here I have setup the same I just need to show each of the activity split by its activity_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is on dc.js version 1.7, which is more than five years old and not something I can wrap my head around. :-/

I converted it to dc.js version 2, which also uses D3 v3.

dc.js is not great at showing the raw data, it's more about showing aggregated data. But in this case it could make sense to create a stack for every `activity_group`; that way it will automatically be assigned its own color.

Using ES6 we can get a list of all `activity_group` like this:

```
const stacks = [...new Set(data.map(row => row.activity_group))];
```

Now let's aggregate the data by stack:

```
var groupActivity = dimByActivity.group().reduce(
    function reduceAdd(p, v) {
        p[v.activity_group] += v.time_taken;
        return p;
    },
    function reduceRemove(p, v) {
        p[v.activity_group] -= v.time_taken;
        return p;
    },
    function reduceInitial() {
        return Object.fromEntries(stacks.map(stack => [stack,0]));
    });
```

This is substantially the same as the [stacked bar example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/stacked-bar.html) except that we have a stack per `activity_group`.

Note that we are creating all the stacks in every bin, just leaving them zero where they don't exist. This is because dc.js expects the same stacks for every X value - it won't work otherwise.

As in the stacked bar example, we'll programmatically add the stacks to the chart, keeping in mind that we need to use `.group()` for the first stack:

```
function sel_stack(valueKey) {
    return function(d) {
    return d.value[valueKey];
  };
}
// ...
stacks.forEach(function(stack, i) {
  if(i===0)
    chanUtil.group(groupActivity, stack, sel_stack(stack));
  else
    chanUtil.stack(groupActivity, stack, sel_stack(stack));
})
```

Here's the output. I messed a little with the margins and height in order to get the legend not to overlap and there are probably smarter ways to deal with this:

[image: demo screenshot]

[Fork of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/5xw7t06v/23/).

As I said, this is making dc.js do something it doesn't want to do, so YMMV!

Comment: Case closed, thank you man. Your reply makes me learn more on this and contribute to you.